# Subreports dependancy

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

Is there a way to show one subreport if the other subreport doesn't have any rows (doesn't return any rows).

What have I tried:

In my first subreport I returned the number of processed rows "REPORT_COUNT" to master report variable "SUBREPORT_VAR". Variable "SUBREPORT_VAR" works as it should. I added additional text field to master report and output variable to it. I set Evaluation time of text field to **[Band](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/variables#Evaluation_Time)**, as without this it doesn't work correctly.

Further I set option "Print When Expression" of the second subreport to:

> $V{SUBBREPORT_VAR} < 1

I use jasper studio 5.5.0 final.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no row count wouldn't the result be null.
If so you you could use this in the print when expression in your second subreport: 
`$V{SUBBREPORT_VAR}==null`

another option is to run the query in your main report and use this as the *subreport expression*:

`IF($F{SOME_VAR_FROM_YOUR_QUERY}==null,subreport2.jasper,subreport1.jasper`

This prints subreport2 when your `SOME_VAR_FROM_YOUR_QUERY` returns null if not it prints subreport1.